# Should I use a facade to access JPA Entities?

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I want to retrieve a product from my database. A product is made up of data from several different tables.

Is it best to create a facade that will talk to multiple entities in order to pull together all the info needed to make a product and should the facade marshal the object or is there another way to do this?

I was thinking the method in the facade would be `getProduct()` and this method would use multiple entities?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a product Entity and have JPA do it all for you?  An entity can span multiple tables, and your product Entity can itself have references to other entities where it makes sense.  Your application can make accessors within the Product class to expose the referenced entities or just return data from those references as needed.